# Informed badge can be tracked on Stack Apps, even though it can't be earned

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackapps, badge-progress, informed-badge

Is the **Informed** badge available for Stack Apps? I didn't see the badge on [All badges](https://stackapps.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=all) or [Bronze badge](https://stackapps.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=bronze)'s Other Badges section (*normally on other sites the informed badge is showing in bronze - other badges section*).

But the Informed Badge is showing as the **Next badge** in my [Activity](https://stackapps.com/users/37357/arulkumar?tab=topactivity) tab. If the badge does not exist, this need not be showing in the **Next badge** tracking.

Adding the screen shot of activity tab for future reference:

[image: Informed Badge]

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/6939/37357)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Informed** badge has been removed from the "Next badge" tracking. Previously it was listed in the **Available** badges section. Now it is not available under the *Available* or *Bronze* section. So the bug has been fixed recently.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Informed removed from Available section]

Answer (score 5):

It's actually not available, probably because on other SE sites [the tour is different](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) and the badge is obtained when you scroll to the bottom. [The Stack Apps tour seems to be special](https://stackapps.com/tour), and hence there's no badge for it.

So this is the bug, but as for now, the badge tracker doesn't differ on all the sites (there're two versions of the badge sets for the badge tracker: one for main, another for meta), let's hope there will be an exception for the Stack Apps.