# Informed badge on Stack Apps

Tags: bug, badges, stackapps

There doesn't appear to be a Meta for [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) so I'm asking this here. The recommended next badge for me is "Informed", but when I click on "Go get it" I'm taken to [this page](https://stackapps.com/tour), which does not appear to award the informed badge for reading.

[image]

So how does one get the Informed badge on Stack Apps?

Comment: One doesn't. [The badge doesn't exist on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/help/badges). The bug is that the badge selection allows choosing that badge, given it does't exist.

Comment: Related: [Informed badge can be tracked on Stack Apps, even though it can't be earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272748/informed-badge-can-be-tracked-on-stack-apps-even-though-it-cant-be-earned)